# Does Google Identity Platform support groups (of users)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

Can we model "business" type in Google Identity Platform - i.e. groups and group administrators? Where a business or group administrator has full control over its members?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Do you have a link to relevant documentation @JohnHanley?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm struggling with this too, any hints?